# "No public or protected classes found to document" error from path with accents

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

My Maven Java 8 project is inside a path which contains accents: `C:\Développements\myproject`.

When I use `maven-javadoc-plugin` (event with last 2.10.4 version) I have this error when I try to generate the javadoc of my project (from IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4):

```
[ERROR] javadoc: warning - No source files for package com.mycompany.myproject
[ERROR] javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
```

This is strange because I have documented classes in this project.

Answer (score 6):

This error can also occur if you have no public methods in your test classes, which is exactly what can happen because Sonar lint rule [S5786](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5786) says JUnits should have default package visibility, for readability.  Fortunately, you can use the -package javadoc option, to fix this.  If you put this in your parent pom:

```
 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
  <junit.version>5.7.0</junit.version>
 </properties>
...
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
     <configuration>
      <source>${java.version}</source>
      <target>${java.version}</target>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.9.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0</version>
     <configuration>
      <source>8</source>
      <additionalOptions>-package</additionalOptions>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
 </build>
 <reporting>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </reporting>
 <distributionManagement>
  <site>
   <id>yourid</id>
   <url>file:///var/www/html/maven</url>
  </site>
 </distributionManagement>
```

then

```
mvn site-deploy
```

will give you your default maven site along with the javadoc.  Included everything relevant for a Java 8 project.

Answer (score 3):

Had this happen when I created a package-private class with a main method. After marking the class as public the packaging step worked again.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Maven or plugin problem but purely a Windows problem. Microsoft is too stupid to have a proper encoding set in `cmd.exe`. You have some stupid DOS encoding. Java's `javadoc`  uses that to read the `@options` file and fails.

Set `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and you are done. Alternatively, use a Linux distribution or FreeBSD.

The issue remains closed.

Comment: Yes it's a Windows problem, but no, it's really a Maven bug because it's it who create the "options" file using UTF-8 encoding, and not the one of the platform used...

Comment: No, it does not: https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-javadoc-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/javadoc/AbstractJavadocMojo.java#L4331
If you think you can provide a good sample project and an idiotproof solution, I would be more than happy to reopen the issue and add it to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a referenced bug from maven-javadoc-plugin project: [MJAVADOC-333](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-333).

So since it is not fixed (it is currently "closed"...) one should just remove the accents from your project path...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the special character (accent) problem, this *may* be a problem with your pom.xml:

I had the same problems right now with a project created in Eclipse.
If you create a project in eclipse, it will put java packages/sources directly within the `src` folder and add the following line to your pom.xml:

`<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`.

If you then decide to move your java files according to the [maven conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and forget to update or remove the *sourceDirectory* tag, you will end up with exactly the same error:

Your project will build fine, but javadoc will not find it`s sources...